# PHP Parse: Syntax Error with echo "\PDOStatement::errorInfo():\n

Tags: php

I am trying to create a page that will delete a row from a database but I keep getting syntax error and when I fix one I get a new error. For example, in the first code I tried re-typing the single quotation and it fixed the first error which was:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''];' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']' in /banking_delete.php on line 11
```

The Code:

```
<?php
include_once 'banking_db.php';
include 'banking_display.php';
# form data
$customer_name=$_POST['customer_name'];
$sql = "delete from customer where customer_name = :customer_name;";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
# data stored in an associative array
$data = array ('customer_name' => $customer_name);
if($stmt->execute($data)){
$rows_affected = $stmt->rowCount();
echo "<h2>".$rows_affected." row deleted sucessfully!</h2>";
display("select customer_name as customer_name, customer_city as customer_city, customer_street as customer_street from customer;”);
} else
{
        echo "\PDOStatement::errorInfo():\n";
        print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
$stmt = null;
$conn = null;
?>
```

After that I got this new error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in /banking_delete.php on line 16
```

When I changed `echo "\PDOStatement::errorInfo():\n";` to `echo "\nPDOStatement::errorInfo():\n";` I still get the same error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a `”` instead of a `"` at the end of

```
display("select customer_name as customer_name, customer_city as customer_city, customer_street as customer_street from customer;”);
```

Comment: I would have thought closing the question as a syntax error with a comment would have been more appopriate.

Comment: @NigelRen yes, me too. But then someone else would have provided it as an answer. So I figured it can just as well be me. And the code will look nicer in an answer.